# Find entity with latest date using Spring Data with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, localdate

Given next object structure:

```
class Foo {
  @Id
  String id;
  LocalDate date;
  ...
}
```

We store these objects in `MongoDB`. Is there any possibility to get entity with the latest date via `MongoRepository` like in the next example?

```
interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {
    @Query(???)
    Foo getByLatestDate(LocalDate date);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try below query.

Using `@Query` annotation

```
@Query("{ 'date' : ?0 }")
Foo getByLatestDate(LocalDate date);
```

Or

Using repository supported keywords

```
Foo findByDate(LocalDate date);
```

Update: Use below query to get latest date.

```
Foo findFirstByOrderByDateDesc();

Foo findTopByOrderByDateDesc();
```

Comment: This will work only if I know what date I am looking for. But I don't know what is the latest date in given entities. And I need to find the record with the latest date. It might be in the past, in the future, whatever.

Comment: Updated to include the repository method to get the latest date from collection. I'll see if I can find equivalent query method.

Comment: Mongo does not recognise these queries.

Comment: oh really. What error do you get ? What is your spring mongo version ?

Comment: sorry, I've made a mistake while implementation. All works. Thank you!